# This code, inside a for loop, contains a timer which only performs once

Tags: for-loop, timer, lua

I want this code to imitate a metronome. How do I get it to keep calling the timer instead of performing the final iteration and stopping?

```
-- main.lua

tempo = 60000/60

for i = 1, 100 do

        local accomp = audio.loadStream("sounds/beep.mp3")
            audio.play(accomp, {channel = 1})
        audio.stopWithDelay(tempo)  

        timer.performWithDelay(tempo, listener) 

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`performWithDelay`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/performWithDelay.html) accepts 3rd parameter for number of loops, you don't need to do it manually.

```
local accomp = audio.loadStream("sounds/beep.mp3")
timer.performWithDelay(tempo, function() audio.play(accomp, {channel = 1}) end, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual...
https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/performWithDelay.html#iterations-optional

You are doing it completely wrong.

`timer.performWithDelay` calls the `listener` function after a given delay.

You don't have to load the file 100 times. Once is enough.
You call the timer function 100 times which does nothing as you don't have any listener function.
Please read the documentation of functions befor you use them so you know what they do and how to properly use them. You can't cook a tasty meal if you don't know anything about your ingredients.

Remove that for loop and implement a listener function.

Use the optional third parameter `iterations` to specify how often you want to repeat that. Use `-1` for infinite repetitions...

Its all there. You just have to RTFM.

Comment: Oleg - thanks, that works fine. Piglet - I'll do that reading you suggest, thanks too.